# How to initialize an array of struct in a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct with an array of another struct inside it and I am having trouble initialising the struct.

```
typedef struct stack * Stack;
typedef struct book * Book;

struct book {
    char *title;
    int pages;
};

struct stack {
    int num_books;
    Book array[50]
};
```

What I am trying to do is to create an empty stack with zero books but I keep getting segmentation faults on everything I tried.

Here is my initialization function:

```
Stack create_stack(void) {
    Stack s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack) * 50);
    s->num_books = 0;
    // s->array[0]->title = Null;
    // s->array[0]->pages = 0;
    // the above 2 lines give a seg fault: 11
    // I also tried:
    // s->array = s->array = malloc(sizeof(struct book) * 50);
    // Which gives the error that array type 'Book [50]' is not assignable
    return s;
}
```

How can I create an empty stack with zero books?

Comment: You need to malloc the Stack as `sizeof(struct stack)`. The "array" of 50 books (which are pointers because of the typedef) comes as part of the `stack` struct.

Comment: Don't ever typedef pointers. It only causes confusion. In particular, what looks like an array of 50 books is actually just an array of 50 pointers. So you need to allocate memory for those pointers before you can use them.

Comment: You asked a similar question today already! You should follow the advices you got with the first question and fixed the flaws/faults first before going on! And there is no "array of `struct` in a `struct`" in your code!

Comment: @Olaf what is the alternative to typedef? For example, if I don't use type def, what will be the return type for create_stack function?

Comment: If you don't know that, you should first learn what `typedef` does. Don't blindly follow some pattern you don't understand. There is absolutely no need for `typedef`. And as Others and I already wrote, it is a strict no-go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory for `struct book` objects. The struct:

```
struct stack {
    int num_books;
    Book array[50];
};
```

defines `array` member as 50 elements array of *pointers* to `book` struct (that is, `Book` is synonym to `struct book *`). These are still "wild" pointers, and you need to assign them with allocated struct objects. In other words, by calling:

```
Stack s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack) * 50);
```

you have made a room for fifty objects of type `struct stack`, but inside each of these structs, there is room for `struct book` pointers, not objects itself.

Like mentioned in comments, typedefing a pointer type is an easy way to obfuscate the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 2

typedef struct book {
char * title ;
int pages;
} Book; 

typedef struct stack {
int num_book;
Book book_arr[SIZE];
} Stack;

//------------------------------------------------

int main (void ){

Stack s1;
  printf("Enter Number of Books : " );
  scanf("%d",&s1.num_book);
  getchar();

     //BOOK
       for( size_t j = 0 ; j < s1.num_book ; j++ ){
         char temp[100];
         printf("Enter the Book Title for %zd Book : ", (j+1) );
         fgets(temp,100,stdin);
         strtok(temp,"\n");     // for removing new line character
     s1.book_arr[j].title = malloc ( sizeof(temp) +1 );
     strcpy(s1.book_arr[j].title,temp);
                    //  puts(s1.book_arr[j].title );
         printf("Enter Pages for %zd Book : ",(j+1) );
     scanf("%d",&s1.book_arr[j].pages); getchar();
      }
            //PRINT
size_t count = 0 ;
       for( size_t i = 0 ; i < s1.num_book ; i++ ){
     while(count < SIZE ) {
       printf("Book Title : %s\nBook pages : %d\n",s1.book_arr[count].title, s1.book_arr[count].pages );
       free(s1.book_arr[count].title );
       count++;
      } 
}       
return 0;
}
```

Is that what you were trying to achieve ?